# Redirect all remaining pages using location block

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx server config file to redirect a few paths on my blog website. For example:

```
location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
        }

location /login {
                rewrite ^/login/index /signup redirect;
                rewrite ^/login/index.php /signup redirect;
                rewrite ^/login/mobile /signup redirect;
        }



.
.
.

...
```

Now I want to redirect "www.example.com/tag_1" to "www.example.com/tags_api.php" so that I can display all articles posts related to "tag_1" when someone request "www.example.com/tag_1".

Also, the number of Tags is quite high and is constantly increasing so I can not use something like this:

```
location  ~ ^/(Tag_1|Tag_2|Tag_3|..|Tag_n)/  {
                rewrite ^/(Tag_1|Tag_2|Tag_3|..|Tag_n) /tags_api.php;
        }
```

So I want to redirect anything of the form "www.example.com/([^/]*)" to "www.example.com/tags.api.php" WITHOUT AFFECTING ANY REDIRECTS THAT ARE ALREADY THERE.